# Why do I get odd behaviour with second, third objects in an array?

Tags: ruby

Here's the code:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :id, :name

  def initialize(init = {})
    init.each do |k, v|
      send("#{k}=", v)
    end
  end
end

people = [ 
  Person.new(:id => 1, :name => "Adam"), 
  Person.new(:id => 2), 
  nil,
]

people.map! do |person|
  person ||= Person.new(:id => 3, :name => "Some default")
  person.name ||= 'Eve'
  person
end

binding.pry
```

and here's what I get in pry:

```
[1] pry(main)> people
=> [#<Person:0x007fc2b0afba98 @id=1, @name="Adam">,
 #<Person:0x007fc2b0afb930 @id=2, @name="Eve">,
 #<Person:0x007fc2b0afb7f0 @id=3, @name="Some default">]
[2] pry(main)> people.first
=> #<Person:0x007fc2b0afba98 @id=1, @name="Adam">
[3] pry(main)> people.second
NoMethodError: undefined method `second' for #<Array:0x007fc2b0afb890>
from (pry):3:in `<main>'
```

I was expecting to be able to access `people.second` and `people.second.id`. What's up?

Comment: Because no method `second` exists.  What's wrong with `people[1]`?

Comment: I think the name is misleading in the ruby [array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-first) documentation.

Comment: @squiguy: What's misleading about it?

Comment: @EdS. I think it makes people imagine there are second and third methods as well, but first takes the first n elements or gives back the first if a number is not passed.

Comment: @squiguy: Then I suppose people should stop assuming and perform the most basic troubleshooting step of checking the documentation.  The "need" for `first` is vastly more common than for `second`, `third`, etc.  This would only be an  issue for absolute beginners.

Comment: @squiguy If people expect `second` and `third`, do they expect `tenth`, `two_hundred_and_thirty_ninth`, `one_million_fifty_sixth`? If so, does this go infinitely? How is that possible in a finite implementation of Ruby? If not, where does it stop? What is the rationale for where is stops?

Comment: Not sure why this question has been down-voted. It's a great answer and clarified any confusion on error messages associated with someone mistakenly assuming there's a .second method in Ruby because it's been mentioned in some other Rails code. And voting to close the question, answers and discussion is hilarious if not a bit sad. I can't see how it's anything other than trying to censor a useful, educational point. E.g. see @Sergio's great points about indexer vs helper methods below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This method does not exist in plain ruby. It's from rails. To use it, you have to include Active Support.

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'

a = [4, 5, 10]

a.first # => 4
a.second # => 5
a.third # => 10
```

But you really shouldn't accustom yourself with accessing array elements in this way. `first`/`last` helpers exist for a reason: very often you need just the first or last element.

```
user = User.where(name: 'Sergio').first # user might not exist
last_transaction = user.transactions.last
```

If you plan on accessing second, third, fourth (and further) elements, there are better options. Iterating with `.each`, for example.

```
user.transactions.each do |tran|
  # ...
end
```

I personally prefer indexer over such helpers* at all times (even when they are available).

1. Indexer form is shorter (`users[1]` vs. `users.second`)
2. They are easier. Consider changing

   ```
   users[1] to users[2]
   ```

   vs.

   ```
   users.second to users.third
   ```

* I mean the helpers that Active Support brings in. I do prefer `first` over `users[0]`.

Comment: +1 for a great answer. And good points about indexer vs helper.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `people[1]`, which is the standard way to access elements in an array.

Requiring "active_support/core_ext" adds a lot of stuff you probably don't need for what amounts to a very small amount of syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer states, this method is from Active Support. But if you don't want to pull in Active Support just for a single method... well, this is Ruby, isn't it?

```
class Array
  def second
    self[1]
  end
end
```

Or, more generally:

```
module Enumerable
  def second
    first = true
    each { |x| first ? (first = false) : return x }
  end
end
```

You could actually include both of those definitions, and for Arrays, the more specific (and probably faster) method will be used. For other types of Enumerables, the more general method will be used.