# How do I convert from a class with "new" to ActiveRecord with "where"?

Tags: ruby, rails-activerecord

I have some code that I'm converting from a simple class to an ActiveRecord class.

The initial code looks like this:

[Why do I get odd behaviour with second, third objects in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821491/ruby-odd-behaviour-with-second-third-objects-in-an-array/16821624?noredirect=1#16821529)

However, rather than `Person.new` I'm using `Person.where`:

```
Person.new(:id => 1, :name => "Adam"),
```

and (slightly contrived for the purposes of fitting with the above):

```
Person.where("id > ?", 0).order(id ASC").first # statement 1
```

And instead of:

```
person ||= Person.new(:id => 3, :name => "Some default")
```

I have:

```
person ||= Person.where("id = 3")
```

This all works fine except when `statement 1` returns nil, for ids above 30213 in my case. Then I get this:

```
@people[1].id
=> 30213

@people[2].id
NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for [#<Person id: 3, name: "Bob">]:ActiveRecord::Relation
from /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:45:in `method_missing'
```

The odd thing is that all the data seems to be correctly initialized:

```
#<Person id: 3, name: "Bob"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`where` returns an array, not a single item, even if only one is found.

That's what the error message is saying: there's no `id` method on an array of people.

If you want to find by id, use `find`:

```
p ||= Person.find(3)
```

Although the domain-level logic leaves me a little confused; where would you use this?

Comment: `where` actually returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` which behaves like an Array for some operations, but is not one.

Comment: @HolgerJust Correct, for the purposes of this question, though, array is close enough.

Comment: Yes, that works. Not clear what you mean by "domain-level logic" though - want to expand...?

Comment: @SnowCrash I mean, why would you ever need to do this? Normally if it's not found you'd need to create one, not create one then optionally replace it with one that's found.